# Trim machine name from Hostinfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, trim, hostname

I want to trim the machine name from my Hostname so that I can get the server name.

But I'm not able to figure out how.

This is my code:

```
 string machineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
 hostinfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(str); //Fetches the name of the system in the Network (SystemName.canon.co.in)   
 string Original = hostinfo.HostName.ToString();
```

Now the string contains the data like:

```
MachineName.ServerName
blah.comp.co.uk
```

So I want to remove `blah.` from the string so that what I am left with is `comp.co.uk`.

Can anyone help me out with it?

Comment: split string using dot and ignore first word and again join it

Comment: So you always want to trim the part before the first dot? What have you tried? (Hint: `string.IndexOf`, `string.Substring`... or `string.Split`.)

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: There's no need to join it - you can split and specify a maximum number of terms as 2...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was trying for string.Subtring. But then I realized that it takes only integer values.

Comment: @Syrion: Well yes, because they're the *indexes* in question. You can use `IndexOf` to find the right index...

Comment: @JonSkeet: So how would I remove the first dot?

Comment: I think you want to parse primary dns suffix for which I'd recommend to not use the hostname (though as always @jonSkeet is correct on how to parse if hostname is what you are going to use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
            string Original = "blah.comp.co.uk";
            string[] ss = Original.Split(".".ToCharArray(), 2);
            string Result = ss[1];
```

EDIT:

```
            string Original = "blah.comp.co.uk";
            string[] ss = Original.Split(new[] {'.'}, 2);
            string Result = ss[1];
```

Comment: A simpler approach than `".".ToCharArray()` is `new[] {'.'}`. Also note that conventionally local variables are camelCased in C#... it's good to get into conventional habits.

Comment: @JonSkeet what will be effect on the code if i used ".".ToCharArray() instead of creating new char array??

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: Well they'll both do the same thing - I just think using a string is an odd way of creating a char array.